# Two Foci on X Windows

Tags: xorg

Is it possible to have two different foci/focuses on X windows? (Basically using two mice and keyboards with one physical machine simultaneously. If so, how is this accomplished?

Comment: On one *machine*, or on one *X server*? The common case "there's only one X server running on this machine, and that's :0.0" is not the only possibility - there can be many X servers running simultaneously and independently. See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiseat_configuration#GNU.2FLinux As for "two focuses on one X Window server" - no.

Comment: One physical machine AND one X server. Two cursors/foci in one X server.

Comment: I think I've seen a "multiple cursors" hack/prototype some years back; but there was only one focus IIRC. This seems to be it: http://multicursor-wm.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With recent Xorg servers, yes. You need to use the XInput Extension version 2.0 or newer. You'll also need a Window Manager capable of doing that, and I'm not sure which of the modern WMs can do that already.

Documentation:

- http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/inputproto/
- http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libXi/
- http://who-t.blogspot.com/ (he's the guy who wrote all this stuff, his blog is full of things to learn)

On Debian Testing I can even get two pointers and start using them right now (one controlled by the USB mouse and the other by the touchpad):

```
pzanoni@vicky:~$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse                         id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lite-On Technology USB Productivity Option Keyboard( has the hub in # 1 )     id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lite-On Technology USB Productivity Option Keyboard( has the hub in # 1 )     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ACPI Virtual Keyboard Device              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
pzanoni@vicky:~$ xinput --create-master my 1 1
pzanoni@vicky:~$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse                         id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lite-On Technology USB Productivity Option Keyboard( has the hub in # 1 )     id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lite-On Technology USB Productivity Option Keyboard( has the hub in # 1 )     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ACPI Virtual Keyboard Device              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
⎡ my pointer                                id=17   [master pointer  (18)]
⎜   ↳ my XTEST pointer                          id=19   [slave  pointer  (17)]
⎣ my keyboard                               id=18   [master keyboard (17)]
    ↳ my XTEST keyboard                         id=20   [slave  keyboard (18)]
pzanoni@vicky:~$ xinput --reattach "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "my pointer"
```